# How to grab data from joined tables in a list of values condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables: `Images` table, `Product` table, and `ProductGallery` table. My Images table have two columns

In this way:

```
ID  Path
1   JeffAtwood.jpg
2   GeoffDalgas.jpg    
3   Jarrod Dixon.jpg    
4   JoelSpolsky.jpg
```

My `Products` table have two columns :

```
ID  Image ID
1   1
2   2 
3   3    
4   4
```

My `ProductGallery` has three columns

```
 ID  ImageID ProductID
    1   1       1
    2   2       1
    3   3       1
    4   4       1
    5   1       2
    6   2       2
    7   3       2
    8   4       2
```

I need to create a stored procedure that return for me all the paths for list of products

So I have a parameter called `@ids NVARCHAR(MAX)`

in which all the products ids that i need is there with a comma separating each value.

so I have :

```
 @ids = '1' + ','+ '2'+',' ..... and so on
```

Any one can help me to write the sql statement does the job for me ?

So far I have this

```
Declare @Ids VARCHAR(MAX)

select @Ids = '1';
select P.ID ,I.Path from Images I
left outer join Products P on (I.ID IN(select ImageID from Products where ID in (SELECT Items FROM Split(@Ids,','))))
left outer join ProductGallery PG on (PG.ImageID = I.ID)
WHERE PG.ProductID IN(SELECT Items FROM Split(@Ids,','))   AND P.ID IN
(SELECT Items FROM Split(@Ids,',')) 
GROUP BY P.ID, I.Path
```

Notice `@Ids` parameter is already filled with values and I will pass it from my C# code.

Comment: Wait a second.. `JeffAtwood.jpg`, `GeoffDalgas.jpg`, `Jarrod Dixon.jpg `and `JoelSpolsky.jpg` ? I smell something bad `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Not at a machine to test but you could try

```
select I.Path from Images I
left outer join Products P on P.ImageID = I.ID
where CHARINDEX(convert(varchar, P.ID), @ids) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your query, I assume you already have a function to split a delimited string.

Try this (to get images from product table, as per comment):

```
Select  p.Id ProductId, i.Path imagePath
From Products p
      Join Images i on p.imageId = i.Id
Where p.Id in (
                       --your Split() function here
                       SELECT Items FROM dbo.Split(@Ids,',')
                      )
```

Comment: Thanks for you response, but this sql will not retun for me the images in the products table,                                                                                                                     it will return the one in the products gallery table only